# Azure Function App failing to load IOptionsFormatter

Tags: c#, azure-functions

I have a C# Azure Function App that I'm trying to run locally. It previously had worked fine some months ago but is now failing with the following:

> A host error has occurred
>   Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage: Could not load type 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Hosting.IOptionsFormatter' from assembly 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host, Version=3.0.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'.

At some point I had updated the **Azure Functions and Web Jobs Tools** to the latest version (15.10.20460.0).

On startup, it was having problems indexing the functions so I updated the **Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions** nuget package reference to the latest version (1.0.24) which is now giving me the above error.

I also added a nuget package reference to **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** 3.0.3 to resolve the missing `TableAttribute` errors that appeared as well.

I've checked the assemblies in the bin folder which have the following versions:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage.dll - v3.0.3.0
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.dll - v3.0.4.0

Comment: Is this a full Framework function? I have a full framework functions project and it was impossible to update any nugets. This is what I have. `Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions (1.0.13)`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs (2.2.0)`, `Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions (2.2.0)`. Things may have changed now though.

Comment: When you hit F5 and the Functions Core Tools window pops up -- what version does it say you're running with? For example, I see `Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12285.0`

Comment: @KosalaW The project is targeting .NET Standard 2.0.

Comment: @brettsam The first two lines say

`Azure Functions Core Tools (2.3.148 Commit hash: f9b3db04f9833b431f1b001efb3e5783a169ebfc)
Function Runtime Version: 2.0.12210.0`

Comment: That's what I suspected - you're running on an old version of the tools somehow. But it looks like all your versions are the newest, so I'm not entirely sure how. I'm checking with an expert now and will come back with some more details shortly.

Comment: Turns out we've got a troubleshooting guide that may help you get on the latest versions -- can you try this? https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-tooling-feed/wiki/Fixing-Azure-Function-Core-Tools-download-issues-for-Visual-Studio

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing the Nuget Package Reference for **Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage** from the latest version - 3.0.3 to 3.0.2 resolves the issue.

Running the function project now launches successfully with no errors displayed.

Comment: this helped me thanks.

What I noted, however, is that 3.0.3 just didn't work locally, but when I published on Azure it did work as expected. So now thanks to you I can test locally again!

Comment: What Kholofelo found also proves @brettsam is right, see last comment in question to download new function cli.

Answer (score 4):

For Visual Studio for Mac 2019 users I found the following to help me.  If you add an azure functions project to your solution there should be a message that there are updated templates available.  Click that, let them update and then cancel adding a new project.

This appears to update the tooling as well.  My error went away.  Not sure why a brand new VS for Mac 2019 install didn't have updated tools.

Comment: This works much better than downgrading the version numbers. We are on 3.0.6 now and the only thing was to upgrade the templates. This is actually the correct answer not the accepted work around.

Comment: Unfortunately I didn't get any such message. Downgrading my package reference using the accepted answer did resolve the error locally.

Comment: @RobbVandaveer the message is a small font link or something near the bottom of the form.  Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I'm using Visual Studio 2019 (16.2.0) with most of my Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions being version 3.0.6.
After trying out all suggestions above without success, I recognized that I was missing the "Connection" attribute in my ServiceBusTrigger.

Adding the connection attribute resolved the issue immediately.