# Azure WebJobs SDK exception: Forbidden when running application

Tags: c#, macos, azure, azure-storage, azurite

I've got a .NET Core application that I need to run on a Mac (11.3.1) for development. The same app runs fine on Windows and apart from the OS, the only difference is that on Mac I have to use [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) for the storage emulation (on Windows the emulation is done using [Azure Storage emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)).

The libraries versions we're using:

- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs **3.0.27**
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions **4.0.1**
- Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage **4.0.4**
- Azurite (via VSCode Extension) **3.12.0**

I have very little experience with the Azure tools and, from what I can tell, the required configuration for it to run is done correctly with the proper connection string set.

The problem I'm having is when I run the application via `dotnet run` I get the following error:

```
Unhandled exception.Unhandled exception.Unhandled exception.   Microsoft.Azure.Storage.StorageException: Forbidden
   at Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Core.Executor.Executor.ExecuteAsync[T](RESTCommand`1 cmd, IRetryPolicy policy, OperationContext operationContext, CancellationToken token)
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Queues.Listeners.QueueListener.ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Storage\Queues\Listeners\QueueListener.cs:line 193
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.TaskSeriesTimer.RunAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken) in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\TaskSeriesTimer.cs:line 147
   at Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Timers.WebJobsExceptionHandler.<>c__DisplayClass3_0.<OnUnhandledExceptionAsync>b__0() in C:\projects\azure-webjobs-sdk-rqm4t\src\Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host\Timers\WebJobsExceptionHandler.cs:line 55
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
Request Information
RequestID:
RequestDate:Wed, 12 May 2021 11:04:39 GMT
StatusMessage:Forbidden
ErrorCode:
```

When looking for a solution I've found [this question here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54510540/azure-function-app-failing-to-load-ioptionsformatter), and although the error message is very similar, I wasn't able to solve the problem with the proposed solution.

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Storage SDK you're using? Also, what's the version of Azurite? Please edit your question and include the code you have written.

Comment: @GauravMantri, I've updated the question with the library versions we're using. As for the code, it is an existing project (I haven't written any code for it) and is fairly large, also I can't due to confidentiality. I understand that limits what help you can offer. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for sharing the details. I think I know why this issue is happening. Let me provide an answer shortly.

Comment: In the meantime please try to run your code against a real storage account instead of Azurite and you should be able to run the code.

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to get that solved at the same time (being able to connect to an existing storage account) but that requires approval from somewhere else on the company and might not happen today for me.

Comment: Hey @GauravMantri, I am able to connect to a remote storage account (a real one), it works just fine. The problem is establishing a connection to Azurite on localhost. Thanks for the suggestion, albeit temporarily, I can do some work with that workaround.

Comment: @GauravMantri Can you send out your answers to help more forum users.

Comment: @GauravMantri I read your previous conversations, and I guess, is there a problem with `Azurite` on MacOS?